# How o open pop up for user approval on react tsx - with stripe payment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I have 3 button for 3 payment options
Iam able to get from theserver the payment intent Id

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import Config from "./Config.jsx";
import ConfigDev from "./ConfigDev.jsx";
import { restApiPostSimple } from "./RestManager.js";
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm.jsx";

const StripeHandler = () => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
  const stripeKey = isDevelopment ? ConfigDev.stripeKey : Config.stripeKey;
  const stripePromise = loadStripe(stripeKey);
  const successUrl = isDevelopment
    ? ConfigDev.apiUrlWithPort + "/public/stripe/webhook"
    : Config.apiUrlWithPort + "/public/stripe/webhook";
  const cancelUrl = isDevelopment
    ? ConfigDev.apiUrlWithPort + "//public/stripe/webhook/cancel"
    : Config.apiUrlWithPort + "/public/stripe/webhook/cancel";
  const createIntentIdPath = "/mobile-payment/create-payment-intent?amount=";
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handlePayment = async (amountToCharge: Number) => {
    try {
      const stripe = await stripePromise;
      if (stripe) {
        const response = await restApiPostSimple(
          createIntentIdPath + amountToCharge
        ); // Amount in cents
        const clientSecret = response.data.clientSecret;

        const cardElement = elements?.getElement(CardElement);

        if (cardElement) {
          const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
              card: cardElement,
              billing_details: {
                name: "Jenny Rosen",
              },
            },
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <div>
          <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(1);
              handlePayment(1);
            }}
          >
              1$  
          </button>{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(5);
              handlePayment(5);
            }}
          >
             5$  
          </button>{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(10);
              handlePayment(10);
            }}
          >
              10$  
          </button>{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </Elements>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StripeHandler;
```

but after response of payment intent fromthe server return I'm stuck
Im not sure how to open the react form of payment.
also after client makes the payment how do i know it in the server ?

Comment: Typically you will want to listen to webhook events to see if a payment has succeeded. You can have your client tell your backend about the successfuly payment, but that method can be unreliable and result in charging customers without your server knowing. Listening to webhooks is the minimum, but many merchants use both methods to take advantage of the strengths of both. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Im not sure how to open the react form of payment"? Your code looks like it will render Stripe's Card Element in React. Is the element not rendering for you? Also, if you are just starting now, it is actually recommended to use the Payment Element as it is more flexible, feature rich, and allows you to more easily start taking other payment methods if you want to. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements